# How does the value variable ans is zero?

Tags: c

Here in the code I am getting value of ans 0 but why is it

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
       int i=9,j=10,k=1,ans;

       ans=i<j>k;

       printf("%d%d%d%d",i,j,k,ans);
       return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Operators `>` and `<` yields 0 or 1. Now calculate.

Comment: well... at least in python we have chained comparisons :)

Comment: the best duplicate I could find concerns c++ (no thanks to SO search engine that forces to use google unfiltered search), but the explanation is the same. If someone comes up with a C dupe, I'll add/edit it